# Objective-C How to detect keyboard extension will hide?

Tags: objective-c, custom-keyboard

I'm developing an app and keyboard extension (UIInputViewController).
I want detect when:

> 1. My keyboard extension will hide.
> 2. Change my keyboard extension to other keyboard (in list keyboard)

Now, I'm using [applicationWillResignActive] to detect but it only catch when press button "Home" on device.

Would you like send me a suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain little more about your requirement.

Comment: @VinuJacob: I want to catch event hide custom keyboard, and event change custom keyboard to other keyboard

Comment: You can use keyboard notificatons.

Answer (score 0):

We use UIInputViewController to create custom-keyboard.

In order to detect event hide custom-keyboard or change custom-keyboard to other keyboard then we can use:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //Do something when hide/change custom-keyboard
}
```

It was simple but I didn't pay attention.